# OCI-Lob could not be converted to string error when Importing an Oracle BLOB into a MySQL one, using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, pdo, blob

For a work, i have to import tables from an Oracle Database into a MySQL one.

Here is my approach to this :

```
$db = "" //Oracle connection    
$connexion = oci_connect(user, login,$db)

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table" //SQL query

$requete2 = oci_parse($connexion, $sql); 
$result2 = oci_execute($requete); // result is useless i think

if (!$requete2) {

    $e = oci_error();   

}else {

    try {

        $conn2 = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", 'login', 'pass');
        $conn2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt2 = $conn2->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO table 
                                ('field1', 'field2', 'field3') 
                                VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $conn2->beginTransaction();

        while (($row2 = oci_fetch_array($requete2, OCI_NUM+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {

               $stmt2->execute($row2);

        }

   }catch(PDOException $e){
       $conn2->rollBack();
       echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();   
   }
    $conn2->commit(); 
}
```

Here is an example of the `var_dump` of the $row2 before the execute statement:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '2541.pdf' (length=29)
  1 => 
    object(OCI-Lob)[5]
      public 'descriptor' => resource(7, oci8 descriptor)
  2 => string 'id' (length=6)
```

And here are the fields i'm trying to insert in :

field1 : VARCHAR
field2 : BLOB
field3 : VARCHAR

Running this code gives me :

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class OCI-Lob could not be converted
>   to string in line 95

With line 95 being `$stmt2->execute($row2);`

trying to bind each parameter, in this fashion :

```
$stmt2->bindParam(1, $row2[0]);
$stmt2->bindParam(2, $row2[1],PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt2->bindParam(3, $row2[2]);
$stmt2->execute();
```

gives me the same error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class OCI-Lob could not be converted
>   to string

And just to see, here is the var_dump of the `$row2[1]` (my blob):

```
object(OCI-Lob)[5]
  public 'descriptor' => resource(7, oci8 descriptor)
```

Thanks.

EDIT : To add some precision, thsi aprroach works like a charm if i only have Strings (i tried it). The problem here comes specifically from the BLOB

Comment: `'field1', 'field2', 'field3'` are string literals, not column names. You need to get rid of those quotes.

Comment: i tried just now to replace 'field' by `field`(repeated for each, ofc) and it didn't changed a thing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDO and OCI8 extensions cannot interact each other the way you intend. More specifically, `PDOStatement::execute()` expects a flat array of values that are either strings or can be cast to strings. The `OCI-Lob` class doesn't implement a `__toString()` magic method, thus the error.

I haven't worked with OCI8 for a while and I can't remember if there's a way to return LOBs as plain strings (which would be one option) but it's pretty straightforward to render a string yourself:

```
while (($row2 = oci_fetch_array($requete2, OCI_NUM+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    $row2[1] = $row2[1]->load();
    $stmt2->execute($row2);
}
```

... or this (to your liking):

```
while (($row2 = oci_fetch_array($requete2, OCI_NUM+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    $stmt2->execute(
        [
            $row2[0],
            $row2[1]->load(),
            $row2[2],
        ]
    );
}
```

Beware this is memory intensive since you're loading the complete LOB into RAM. If you need to manipulate large values, you'll have to research on [PDO LOBs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php).

Also, this code will break when you add more columns to the oracle table or alter their position. I suggest you replace `SELECT *` with a proper column list.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this the moment I get back to my office